# Using Bluetooth with a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth

I've seen the experimental API for using Bluetooth has been recently released and I wanted to perform a few tests. I've looked at the official documentation at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.bluetooth.html but even the most simple example won't work. Of course, I previously set the permissions correctly in order to use the experimental APIs.

My background.js looks like this:

```
function booleanCallback(result) {
    alert(result.toString());
}

chrome.experimental.bluetooth.isPowered(booleanCallback);
```

No matter what, `result` is always `undefined`. Any thoughts on this?

Cheers.

Comment: There's a big fat warning on that page regarding this extension potentially not being compatible with release versions of Chrome - do you test against a TRUNK version?

Comment: I'm using the Canary version yeah ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bluetooth API is currently only implemented on Chrome OS. There are open issues for the implementation on [Windows](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135470), [Mac](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135472) and [Linux](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135467). You may want to star one or more of those to be updated when the API is available on more platforms.